# Check whether network response is coming from server or Firefox cache

Tags: firefox, caching, request, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

In Mozilla Firefox, how you can check which files are served from the browser cache, and which comes from the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) displays the word "cached" for requests that are served from the browser cache in the *Transferred* column. All requests that have a size listed there, come from the server.

[image: Cached network requests]